# Null space for linear map injectivity?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrix-rank

The null space of a linear map $\mathcal A:U\to V$ is:

$$
\text{Null}(\mathcal A)=\{u\in U|\mathcal A(u)=0_V\}
$$

For $\mathcal A$ to be linear, we require that $\text{Null}(\mathcal A)=\{0_U\}$, i.e. the addition identity element on linear space $U$.

**Question**: why does $\text{Null}(\mathcal A)=\{0_U\}$ mean that the null space is dimension 0? In other words, the nullity of the matrix representation is 0. For me, as there is one element in the null space ($0_U$), shouldn't the dimension be 1?

Comment: The set with just the zero vector is not one-dimensional. A one-dimensional space is a "line," that is, the set consisting of all scalar multiples of a non-zero vector. The 0-dimensional thing may look a little weird, but it certainly is smaller than a 1-dimensional space. (In theory, you'd say that a basis for the 0 space is the empty set -- but that's probably not too satisfying either.) And it does make rank-nullity work out!

Comment: Do You mean for $\mathcal{A}$ to be linear, we require $0_U\in Null (\mathcal{A})$? Because we clearly don´t require $Null(\mathcal{A})=\{0_U\}$, since e.g. $\mathcal{A}\equiv 0_V$ is linear and $Null(\mathcal{A})=U$ in this case. As to Your question, there is an element in $\{0_U\}$, but it has no linearly independant subset, except $\emptyset$, which has $0$ elements, therefore dimension $0$.